# How to display JSON Data onto a UITableView

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am using Xamarin.iOS to return a JSON and attempt to place it on a UITableView, however I cannot seem to get it to work, here is what I am attempting to do so far:

**Main View Controller**

This is how I am returning the JSON

```
var request = new RestRequest {RootElement = "data", Resource = "/users/self/feed"};
request.AddParameter("access_token", instagramAccessToken);

var client = new RestClient ("https://api.instagram.com/v1");

   // Edited Client Execution
   client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
            {
                RootObject rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response.Content);
                table.Source = new TableSource(rootObject.data);
                table.ReloadData();
            }
        );
```

**TableSource Class**

```
    public List<RootObject> Data { get; set; }
    protected string cellIdentifier = "TableCell";

    public TableSource ()
    {
        Data = new List<T> ();
    }

    public TableSource(List<T> data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }

    public override int RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, int section)
    {
        return Data.Count;
    }

    public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        if (OnRowSelected != null) {
            OnRowSelected (this, new RowSelectedEventArgs (tableView, indexPath));
        }
    }

    public class RowSelectedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public UITableView tableView { get; set; }
        public NSIndexPath indexPath { get; set; }

        public RowSelectedEventArgs(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath) : base()
        { 
            this.tableView = tableView;
            this.indexPath = indexPath;
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<RowSelectedEventArgs> OnRowSelected;

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier);
        // if there are no cells to reuse, create a new one
        if (cell == null)
            cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellIdentifier);

                    // Edited Text 
        cell.TextLabel.Text = ((Datum)Data[indexPath.Row]).user.username;

        return cell;
    }
```

I didn't really have a concrete method of displaying the JSON on the Table, so I would be pretty open to radical change. BTW the JSON loads on the `MainViewController` perfectly.

**JSON Response**

Most of your suggestions don't take into consideration how the JSON looks like so here you go:

```
{
        "pagination": {
            "next_url": "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed?access_token=6489401.88b3fb2.7af2a0355ea24f4590efa1ee82ed0a49&max_id=668439962408115415_16915182",
            "next_max_id": "668439962408115415_16915182"
        },
        "meta": {
            "code": 200
        },
        "data": [
            {
                "attribution": null,
                "tags": [
                    "selfie"
                ],
                "type": "image",
                "location": null,
                "comments": {
                    "count": 0,
                    "data": []
                },
                "filter": "Normal",
                "created_time": "1393953134",
                "link": "http://instagram.com/p/lIO1_jmkkr/",
                "likes": {
                    "count": 14,
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "username": "muahjay",
                            "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_304620904_75sq_1392618687.jpg",
                            "id": "304620904",
                            "full_name": "Jeanettee Nicole Cambero Gamez"
                        },
                        {
                            "username": "iam_mrsmith31",
                            "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_32806209_75sq_1392607367.jpg",
                            "id": "32806209",
                            "full_name": "Kiondrix Smith"
                        },
                        {
                            "username": "anniyalation",
                            "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_30752906_75sq_1390523572.jpg",
                            "id": "30752906",
                            "full_name": "Niya G."
                        },
                        {
                            "username": "fonzo_badmon",
                            "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_271402803_75sq_1393641486.jpg",
                            "id": "271402803",
                            "full_name": "Slimshady"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "images": {
                    "low_resolution": {
                        "url": "http://distilleryimage11.s3.amazonaws.com/e02592b0a3bf11e3b63212d269f676eb_6.jpg",
                        "width": 306,
                        "height": 306
                    },
                    "thumbnail": {
                        "url": "http://distilleryimage11.s3.amazonaws.com/e02592b0a3bf11e3b63212d269f676eb_5.jpg",
                        "width": 150,
                        "height": 150
                    },
                    "standard_resolution": {
                        "url": "http://distilleryimage11.s3.amazonaws.com/e02592b0a3bf11e3b63212d269f676eb_8.jpg",
                        "width": 640,
                        "height": 640
                    }
                },
                "users_in_photo": [],
                "caption": {
                    "created_time": "1393953134",
                    "text": "#Selfie",
                    "from": {
                        "username": "kthompkins7",
                        "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_5941681_75sq_1378508674.jpg",
                        "id": "5941681",
                        "full_name": "kthompkins7"
                    },
                    "id": "668849828018145517"
                },
                "user_has_liked": false,
                "id": "668849827690989867_5941681",
                "user": {
                    "username": "kthompkins7",
                    "website": "",
                    "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_5941681_75sq_1378508674.jpg",
                    "full_name": "kthompkins7",
                    "bio": "",
                    "id": "5941681"
                }
            },
            {
                "attribution": null,
                "tags": [
                    "rp",
                    "amen"
                ],
                "type": "image",
                "location": null,
                "comments": {
                    "count": 5,
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "created_time": "1393949795",
                            "text": "@tmcmc Dobson a Christian!!!!",
                            "from": {
                                "username": "keelanwillison",
                                "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_26089241_75sq_1380511035.jpg",
                                "id": "26089241",
                                "full_name": "Keelanwillison"
                            },
                            "id": "668821819276579152"
                        },
                        {
                            "created_time": "1393950029",
                            "text": "Yo my cousin got me a singed autograph from you at the Boston boat show thanks man  @a_dobson3",
                            "from": {
                                "username": "danthebigboy914",
                                "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_27354625_75sq_1393859632.jpg",
                                "id": "27354625",
                                "full_name": "Danny Chiappetta"
                            },
                            "id": "668823778033324461"
                        },
                        {
                            "created_time": "1393950659",
                            "text": "Amen",
                            "from": {
                                "username": "sandyrodr",
                                "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_44889389_75sq_1361591427.jpg",
                                "id": "44889389",
                                "full_name": "sandyrodr"
                            },
                            "id": "668829062428545715"
                        },
                        {
                            "created_time": "1393950664",
                            "text": "",
                            "from": {
                                "username": "cherydaily",
                                "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_18483862_75sq_1379884114.jpg",
                                "id": "18483862",
                                "full_name": "Andrew \"Drew\" Chery"
                            },
                            "id": "668829109488636596"
                        },
                        {
                            "created_time": "1393951921",
                            "text": "Amen",
                            "from": {
                                "username": "bostonsonia",
                                "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_182219303_75sq_1391293289.jpg",
                                "id": "182219303",
                                "full_name": "Sonia"
                            },
                            "id": "668839648625348773"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "filter": "Normal",
                "created_time": "1393949714",
                "link": "http://instagram.com/p/lIIUdggtOj/",
                "likes": {
                    "count": 324,
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "username": "bwest05",
                            "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_387702554_75sq_1393739891.jpg",
                            "id": "387702554",
                            "full_name": "bb"
                        },
                        {
                            "username": "babygirl6193",
                            "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_23365060_75sq_1384972330.jpg",
                            "id": "23365060",
                            "full_name": "babygirl6193"
                        },
                        {
                            "username": "derekmooney1",
                            "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_218356294_75sq_1388601101.jpg",
                            "id": "218356294",
                            "full_name": "Derek Mooney"
                        },
                        {
                            "username": "zay0613",
                            "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_342812999_75sq_1369576584.jpg",
                            "id": "342812999",
                            "full_name": "Zay"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "images": {
                    "low_resolution": {
                        "url": "http://distilleryimage11.s3.amazonaws.com/0e1b270aa3b811e395af12cdc849cb9b_6.jpg",
                        "width": 306,
                        "height": 306
                    },
                    "thumbnail": {
                        "url": "http://distilleryimage11.s3.amazonaws.com/0e1b270aa3b811e395af12cdc849cb9b_5.jpg",
                        "width": 150,
                        "height": 150
                    },
                    "standard_resolution": {
                        "url": "http://distilleryimage11.s3.amazonaws.com/0e1b270aa3b811e395af12cdc849cb9b_8.jpg",
                        "width": 640,
                        "height": 640
                    }
                },
                "users_in_photo": [],
                "caption": {
                    "created_time": "1393949714",
                    "text": "#RP from @flashgoodwin #AMEN",
                    "from": {
                        "username": "a_dobson3",
                        "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_203045179_75sq_1374262647.jpg",
                        "id": "203045179",
                        "full_name": "a_dobson3"
                    },
                    "id": "668821135462420769"
                },
                "user_has_liked": false,
                "id": "668821135110099875_203045179",
                "user": {
                    "username": "a_dobson3",
                    "website": "",
                    "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_203045179_75sq_1374262647.jpg",
                    "full_name": "a_dobson3",
                    "bio": "",
                    "id": "203045179"
                }
            },
            {
                "attribution": null,
                "tags": [
                    "tb12"
                ],
                "type": "image",
                "location": null,
                "comments": {
                    "count": 169,
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "created_time": "1393952642",
                            "text": "My guy! The greatest! I just want him to get another ring so the haters can stop saying he hasn't won one since 04. I mean he still won them right? #TomBrady @patriots",
                            "from": {
                                "username": "k_aus32",
                                "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_39840771_75sq_1390431094.jpg",
                                "id": "39840771",
                                "full_name": "k_aus32"
                            },
                            "id": "668845703585318559"
                        },
                        {
                            "created_time": "1393952673",
                            "text": "@heres_jonni9",
                            "from": {
                                "username": "allyson21lautner",
                                "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_184895764_75sq_1393107648.jpg",
                                "id": "184895764",
                                "full_name": "Allyson "
                            },
                            "id": "668845962264823470"
                        },
                        {
                            "created_time": "1393952694",
                            "text": "Let's go !",
                            "from": {
                                "username": "tom12terrific",
                                "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_421023272_75sq_1393644166.jpg",
                                "id": "421023272",
                                "full_name": "Andrew Estrada"
                            },
                            "id": "668846135581853361"
                        },
                        {
                            "created_time": "1393952856",
                            "text": "♡",
                            "from": {
                                "username": "in_neverland74",
                                "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_181245582_75sq_1391928288.jpg",
                                "id": "181245582",
                                "full_name": "Karen"
                            },
                            "id": "668847491935880949"
                        },
                        {
                            "created_time": "1393952914",
                            "text": "Follow for patriots pics daily!! (Ifollowback)",
                            "from": {
                                "username": "ne_patriots_fanpage__",
                                "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_983242248_75sq_1391989748.jpg",
                                "id": "983242248",
                                "full_name": "New England Patriots Fanpage"
                            },
                            "id": "668847980295472912"
                        },
                        {
                            "created_time": "1393952952",
                            "text": "Best ever; period.  Let's see anyone win a ring with the humps he's had to work with, (except Randy).",
                            "from": {
                                "username": "calidoso76",
                                "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_1101426299_75sq_1392654362.jpg",
                                "id": "1101426299",
                                "full_name": "calidoso76"
                            },
                            "id": "668848301545604900"
                        },
                        {
                            "created_time": "1393953005",
                            "text": "Shit just because brady hasn't won a ring since 04 don't mean a thing....one more and he'll have 6.....the most superbowl wins than ANY quarterback EVER. @patriots",
                            "from": {
                                "username": "inkandartsosick",
                                "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_260242163_75sq_1363337609.jpg",
                                "id": "260242163",
                                "full_name": "Eric Hughes"
                            },
                            "id": "668848744304723771"
                        },
                        {
                            "created_time": "1393953023",
                            "text": "",
                            "from": {
                                "username": "bvsed_papi_",
                                "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_408657565_75sq_1393905141.jpg",
                                "id": "408657565",
                                "full_name": "Abel Valle™"
                            },
                            "id": "668848894913791811"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "filter": "Lo-fi",
                "created_time": "1393949267",
                "link": "http://instagram.com/p/lIHd-_v8Uj/",
                "likes": {
                    "count": 13685,
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "username": "dollathebarber",
                            "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_219503241_75sq_1373905843.jpg",
                            "id": "219503241",
                            "full_name": "dollathebarber"
                        },
                        {
                            "username": "emastro23",
                            "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_21122956_75sq_1388823730.jpg",
                            "id": "21122956",
                            "full_name": "Eddie Mastrocola"
                        },
                        {
                            "username": "pat_fan99",
                            "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_304601453_75sq_1377084414.jpg",
                            "id": "304601453",
                            "full_name": "Timothy Smith"
                        },
                        {
                            "username": "___adam___q",
                            "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_3694047_75sq_1367384028.jpg",
                            "id": "3694047",
                            "full_name": "Adam Quinonez"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "images": {
                    "low_resolution": {
                        "url": "http://distilleryimage10.s3.amazonaws.com/1c67f514a3b711e383121299eef1f922_6.jpg",
                        "width": 306,
                        "height": 306
                    },
                    "thumbnail": {
                        "url": "http://distilleryimage10.s3.amazonaws.com/1c67f514a3b711e383121299eef1f922_5.jpg",
                        "width": 150,
                        "height": 150
                    },
                    "standard_resolution": {
                        "url": "http://distilleryimage10.s3.amazonaws.com/1c67f514a3b711e383121299eef1f922_8.jpg",
                        "width": 640,
                        "height": 640
                    }
                },
                "users_in_photo": [],
                "caption": {
                    "created_time": "1393949267",
                    "text": "#tb12",
                    "from": {
                        "username": "patriots",
                        "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_1939080_75sq_1385924433.jpg",
                        "id": "1939080",
                        "full_name": "New England Patriots"
                    },
                    "id": "668817391815214218"
                },
                "user_has_liked": false,
                "id": "668817391496447267_1939080",
                "user": {
                    "username": "patriots",
                    "website": "",
                    "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_1939080_75sq_1385924433.jpg",
                    "full_name": "New England Patriots",
                    "bio": "",
                    "id": "1939080"
                }
            },
            {
                "attribution": null,
                "videos": {
                    "low_resolution": {
                        "url": "http://distilleryimage4.s3.amazonaws.com/2cb7114aa3b511e3a3e312f545262070_102.mp4",
                        "width": 480,
                        "height": 480
                    },
                    "standard_resolution": {
                        "url": "http://distilleryimage4.s3.amazonaws.com/2cb7114aa3b511e3a3e312f545262070_101.mp4",
                        "width": 640,
                        "height": 640
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

After those two Edits I still have two errors:

Error on Main View Controller
[image: Picture 1]

Error on Table Source
[image: Picture 2]

Comment: what is the point of repeatedly assigning the Source.Data property in a foreach loop?

Comment: Did you reload your tableview when you gets the whole response.?

Comment: Use TableSource<Datum>(rootObject.Data)

Comment: @SKall Thanks, but the second error still occurs..

Comment: You are using generics (T) on the source but you should be using Datum instead since the source is not meant to be generic. Replace List<RootObject> and List<T> with List<Datum>. You could do (Data[indexPath.Row] as Datum) but that would bad practice.

Comment: @SKall How would you load more cells when you get to the bottom of the table view when you get to the bottom of the table view using the SimplyMobile library. Please see my detailed question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23724953/pseudocode-for-detecting-bottom-of-tableview/23725668?noredirect=1#23725668

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to assign the Data multiple times. Assign the source once and then call ReloadData().

```
   client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
            {
                var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response.Content);
                table.InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        table.Source = new TableSource(rootObject.data);
                        table.ReloadData();
                    });
            }
        );
```

EDIT: It seems there are four items in the Datum field and the last one is null.

https://github.com/sami1971/SimplyMobile/blob/master/iOS/Samples/TwitterSample/Twitter.cs

ToString() override for Datum:

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (user == null)
        {
            return "User is null";
        }
        return user.full_name;
    }
```

For full sample download the project, open iOS/SimplyMobile.iOS.sln and run Samples/TwitterSample.

Comment: Updated with a sample project uploaded to GitHub

Comment: Change it to what you want to display.

Comment: Use a different cell type, or create a custom table cell.

Comment: Then the best option is to create a custom table cell. I updated the sample project to use a custom cell with an image and couple of labels.

Comment: Something like this? https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-RCCgvD3WHOU/UxfhSZnUwlI/AAAAAAAALL0/11IGMbrULzw/w852-h1278/iOS+Simulator+Screen+shot+Mar+5,+2014,+9.43.40+PM.png

Comment: If it does complain about missing dependencies then consider using NuGet to obtain them.

Comment: You would need to reference three DLL's: SimplyMobile.Core & SimplyMobile.IoC both of which are PCL (for all platforms) and then SimplyMobile.Data from the iOS side.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in RowsInSection, GetHeightForRow & (UITableViewCell) GetCell methods. If nothing fires up there then the data source is probably empty.

Comment: Where are you getting the "new TableSource"? I only have "new UITableViewSource"

Comment: It was his custom implementation of UITableViewDataSource. See the TableSource class on the OP's post.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
cell.TextLabel.Text = ((Datum)Data[indexPath.Row]).user.username;
```

Comment: Yes, and each element in your data has a user with a username.

Comment: Can you please see the New New Updated Question

Answer (score 1):

you have to reload tableView when all data retrived from url to your dictionary or array.

you can do this like this

```
[self.Yourtableview reloadData];
```