# Pseudocode for detecting bottom of TableView

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am trying to detect when the user gets to the bottom of the table in `Xamarin.iOS`. I have created this pseudocode in order to detect the bottom, however as soon as the application runs it prints that it is already at the bottom of the table when in fact it is not..

```
float height = tableView.Frame.Size.Height;
float contentYoffset = tableView.ContentOffset.Y;
float distanceFromBottom = tableView.ContentSize.Height - contentYoffset;

if (distanceFromBottom < height) {
    Console.WriteLine ("Bottom of Table");

    }
```

Any suggestions to improve this code or any better methods of detecting the bottom?

Here is my TableView.cs Class:

```
public class TableView : UITableView, ITableCellProvider<Datum>
{
    public TableView ()
    {
    }

    public TableView (IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
    }

    public UITableViewCell GetCell (Datum item)
    {
        var newCell = this.DequeueReusableCell(InstagramCell.Key) 
            as InstagramCell ?? InstagramCell.Create();

        newCell.Bind (item);

        return newCell;
    }

    public float GetHeightForRow (NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        return 340f;
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't you ask the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23622465/pull-down-for-more-cells) 4 days ago?

Comment: @Jason yes using that information i created this question.

Comment: @Jason sorry for being redundant but this issue has been troubling me for some time..

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
  if (indexPath.Section + 1 == NumberOfSections(tableView) && RowsInSection(tableView, indexPath.Section) == indexPath.Row + 1) {
    // this is the last row in the last section
  }
}
```

Comment: In my TableView class I have another GetCell method which is like this

Comment: ` public UITableViewCell GetCell (Datum item)
  {
   var newCell = this.DequeueReusableCell(InstagramCell.Key) 
    as InstagramCell ?? InstagramCell.Create();

   newCell.Bind (item);

   return newCell;
  }`

Comment: Yes, and you can add my code to your GetCell() to determine if this cell is the last one in your table.  Since GetCell() is only called if a cell is visible, that should be a decent test if the user is at the end of the table.

Comment: I am not using a TableViewSource class and am using a Table view subclass to display cells would it still work?

Comment: I'm not clear on how you have a TableView without any source?  Regardless, you should be able to determine if the item you're displaying in GetCell is the the last item in your list or not.

Comment: I cannot do that because I cant change the parameters of my GetCell method.. See my revised question please.

Comment: My answer assumed you were using a standard TableView.  Apparently you are using SimplyMobile, which you failed to mention anywhere in your question.  If you can't do what you need to do with this pattern, then either modify it or switch to a standard TableViews.  Or ask the author of that library for help.